# Hybris 18.08 - MySQL db error for B2C installation

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

**Hybris 18.08**

I'm trying Hybris B2C Installation with **MySQL 5.7.25** as db, but no luck so far. **Getting db related error**. It works fine with default HSQL.

**local.properties**

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbnew?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC  
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
db.username=hybris
db.password=hybris
mysql.allow.fractional.seconds=true
# other *mandatory* settings
db.customsessionsql=SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
mysql.optional.tabledefs=CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
mysql.tabletype=InnoDB
```

User 'Hybris' got full privileges.

Tried,

1) Installing receipe  - `/installer/ ./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus`

2) `ant modulegen -Dinput.module=accelerator -Dinput.name=training4 -Dinput.package=com.hybris.training4 -Dinput.template=develop`

3) removed unnecessary extensions and added the below extensions,

- training4fulfilmentprocess
- training4cockpits
- training4core
- training4facades
- training4test
- training4initialdata
- training4storefront

4) 'ant clean all' was success

5) But 'ant intialize' fails with error,

> ...    [java] ERROR [ImpExWorker<9/16>] [Registry] line 16 at main
>   script: cannot activate tenant <> since its database
>   connection is currently lost
>
> ...  [java] ERROR [ImpExWorker<9/16>] [ConnectionImpl] error resetting
>   isolation level
>        [java]  de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.RecoveryInProgressException:
>   Recovery in progress. Please try again later.
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.get(SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.java:67)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.JDBCInterceptor.get(JDBCInterceptor.java:69)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.ConnectionWithJDBCInterceptor.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionWithJDBCInterceptor.java:147)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>
> ...
>        [java] WARN  [main] (00000006-ImpEx-Import) [SQLErrorCodesFactory] Error while extracting database name - falling
>   back to empty error codes
>        [java]  org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.RecoveryInProgressException:
>   Recovery in progress. Please try again later.
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:338)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:365)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:212)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
>   [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>
> ...
>        [java]   at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118)
>   [ybootstrap.jar:?]
>        [java] Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.RecoveryInProgressException:
>   Recovery in progress. Please try again later.
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>        [java]   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:325)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>        [java]   ... 67 more
>        [java] Caused by: de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.RecoveryInProgressException:
>   Recovery in progress. Please try again later.
>
> ...
>        [java] ERROR [main] [FlexibleSearch] Flexible search error occured...
>        [java] ERROR [main] [CommerceServicesSystemSetup] Importing [/commerceservices/import/constraints.impex]... FAILED
>        [java]  de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException:
>   [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.UniqueAttributesInterceptor@4d54d507]:
>   unexpected validator error: SQL search error - Recovery in progress.
>   Please try again later. query = 'null', values =
>   [PropertyValue:8796093088345, 00000003, 8796100591698, 8796100165714,
>   8796100427858, 8796099870802, 8796100722770, 8796099608658,
>   8796100034642, 8796100526162, 8796099936338, 8796099969106,
>   8796100198482, 8796100362322, 8796100329554, 8796099641426,
>   8796099739730, 8796100100178, 8796100132946, 8796100558930,
>   8796100395090, 8796099674194, 8796099706962, 8796099805266,
>   8796099838034, 8796093513810, PropertyValue:8796093088345, 00000003,
>   8796100296786]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.wrapper.ModelWrapper.invokeValidateInterceptors(ModelWrapper.java:315)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.wrapper.ModelWrapper.validate(ModelWrapper.java:239)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>
> ...    [java] INFO  [main] [TypeLocalization] 8 threads will be used
>   to localize type system.
>        [java] ERROR [main] [AbstractAntPerformable] Error occurred while performing ant task
>        [java]  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given master data source DataSourceImpl<> seemed to be invalid (cannot connnect
>   = true ), (pool closed = false)
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.system.impl.DefaultInitLockDao.assertDataSourceValid(DefaultInitLockDao.java:91)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.system.impl.DefaultInitLockDao.getInitializedMasterDataSource(DefaultInitLockDao.java:80)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.system.impl.DefaultInitLockDao.readLockInfo(DefaultInitLockDao.java:112)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>
> ...
>        [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        [java]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        [java]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>        [java]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>        [java]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>        [java]   at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:142)
>        [java]   at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118)
>        [java] Caused by: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `try
>
>        {                                    de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AntPerformable p = new de.hybris.a . . . '' : Method Invocation p.doPerform : at Line: 4 : in
>   file: inline evaluation of:`try
>        {            de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AntPerformable p = new de.hybris.a . . . '' : p .doPerform ( ) 
>        [java] 
>        [java] Target exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given master data source DataSourceImpl<> seemed to be
>   invalid (cannot connnect = true ), (pool closed = false)
>        [java] 
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:97)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46)
>        [java]   at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86)
>        [java]   at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>        [java]   at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>        [java]   at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
>        [java]   at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:49)
>        [java]   ... 6 more
>        [java] shutting down hybris registry..

Comment: Have you added MySQL connector/driver to `${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/lib/dbdriver`?

Comment: @HybrisHelp I have this jar mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar under dbdriver.

Comment: MySQL Connector needs to be at least version 5.1.x, however, version 8.x is incompatible. [Read more...](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c71300f866910149b40c88dfc0de431.html)

Comment: @HybrisHelp As per my understanding, MySQL Server 8.x is incompatible , but my MySQL Server  is 5.7 .  From the connector download page, 'MySQL Connector/J 8.0 is highly recommended for use with MySQL Server 8.0, 5.7, 5.6, and 5.5. ....'

Comment: I'm not sure about this and never experienced it, but just wanted to highlight it to you.

Answer (score 0):

As per Hybris Help of 1808 - https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c71300f866910149b40c88dfc0de431.html - you need to use MySQL 5.6 or MySQL 5.7.

I would also suggest using 5.1.x DB Driver. I used 8.x before, and it couldn't connect. Maybe the latest 8.x DB Driver has been fixed, but I would try 5.1.x first.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by your environment. It's not a hybris bug.

Check your mysql. (Reinstall it, and when you create the schema, check your encoding. Should be utf8 - default, not general_ci).

And use mysql connector 5.1.x.

I had this bug only on Windows. When I use Linux, everything was OK.